# Joining 2 records on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In this table when an entry is made 2 records are entered into the same table, they can be associated with the field aref as these are the same.

in one of the 2 records the bda is always a blank field but the other records will always have the bda in it. I need to pull this bda out with the rest of the data

Can someone help me get this query sorted, here is what I have so far

```
SELECT ada,bda,sum(adur) / 60 as atime ,count(adur) as calls  
FROM cr_cdr 
WHERE script_res = 'sam0000' 
    AND adetdate BETWEEN CAST('2012-06-11 00:00:00 AM' AS datetime) 
    AND CAST('2012-06-11 11:59:59 PM' AS datetime) 
GROUP BY ada,bda
```

Comment: I'd like to comment on how terrible your column naming conventions are. Also `I have a table which each record has a corresponding record in the same table which has the same field called aref` is a very confusing statement.

Comment: This table I have no control over. It is specific to the hardware which runs on it. I will try and change my description however.

Answer (score 0):

You might try joining the table to itself. Something like this:

```
SELECT c1.ada,c2.bda / 60 as atime ,count(c1.adur) as calls  
FROM 
cr_cdr c1
INNER JOIN
cr_cdr c2
ON( c1.aref = c2.aref )
WHERE 
c2.bda IS NOT NULL 
    AND c1.script_res = 'sam0000' 
    AND c1.adetdate BETWEEN CAST('2012-06-11 00:00:00 AM' AS datetime) 
    AND CAST('2012-06-11 11:59:59 PM' AS datetime) 
GROUP BY aref
```